# How I remove this space at my fragments?( android studio)Error produced when I add the second fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, whitespace

Why appear white space?? How can removed the space? The white space appear in two fragments.

[image]

This error started when I add the second fragment, and I think that is caused by the existence of two bars at the same position in different frames or by the dimens. It should be noted that in different mobiles the space seem have different size. Before add the second fragment, first it worked fine. This are the codes. Code XML of first fragment:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="nutriapp.nut.nut.fragments.PrincipalFragment">
        <devs.mulham.horizontalcalendar.HorizontalCalendarView
            android:id="@+id/calendarView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:background="@color/colorPrimary3"
            app:textColorSelected="#000000" />
        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/me_quedo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="70dp"
            android:text="@string/chek1"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            />


        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:layout_marginBottom="180dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="230dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="232dp">

        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

Code of first fragment:

```
private HorizontalCalendar horizontalCalendar;

    ViewPager viewPager;
    Dinner dinner;
    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
    public PrincipalFragment(){

    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_principal, container, false);


        final java.util.Calendar startDate = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
        startDate.add(java.util.Calendar.MONTH, -2);

        java.util.Calendar endDate = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
        endDate.add(java.util.Calendar.MONTH, 2);

        horizontalCalendar = new HorizontalCalendar.Builder(rootView, R.id.calendarView)
                .range(startDate, endDate)
                .datesNumberOnScreen(5)
                .configure()

                .formatMiddleText("dd")
                .formatBottomText("yyy")
                .textSize(14f, 24f, 14f)
                .showTopText(true)
                .showBottomText(false)
                .textColor(Color.WHITE, Color.WHITE)
                .end()
                .build();

        horizontalCalendar.setCalendarListener(new HorizontalCalendarListener() {



            @Override
            public void onDateSelected(final java.util.Calendar date, int position) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), DateFormat.format("EEE, MMM d, yyyy", date) + " is selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                CheckBox cbFilter = (CheckBox) rootView.findViewById(R.id.me_quedo);
                CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener myCheckboxListener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                        switch (buttonView.getId()){
                            case R.id.me_quedo:
                                if (isChecked)
                                    databaseHelper.addDinner(dinner);
                                break;
                            default:
                                    databaseHelper.DeleteDinner(dinner);
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                };


                }
            });

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Code XML of second fragment:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="nutriapp.nut.nut.fragments.ShopFragment">



    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary2"
        app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary2"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/nav_selector"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/nav_selector"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu"
         />
    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Code second fragment:

```
public class ShopFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback,GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,LocationListener {

    private static final int MY_PERMISSION_CODE = 1000;
    GoogleMap map;
    private GoogleApiClient client;
    private LocationRequest locationRequest;
    private Location lastlocation;
    private Marker currentLocationmMarker;


    public static final int REQUEST_LOCATION_CODE = 99;
    int PROXIMITY_RADIUS = 10000;
    private double latitude, longitude;
    private int contentView;
    IGoogleApiService mService;
    private int[] grantResults;

    private static ShopFragment newInstance() {
        ShopFragment fragment = new ShopFragment();
        return fragment;
    }
    private synchronized void bulidGoogleApiClient() {
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getContext())
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        client.connect();

    }
    //@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_shop,null,false);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) this.getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        mService = Common.getGoogleApiService();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            checkLocationPermission();
        }
        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.action_hospital:
                        nearByPlace("hospital");
                        break;
                    case R.id.action_market:
                        nearByPlace("market");
                        break;
                    case R.id.action_restaurant:
                        nearByPlace("restaurant");
                        break;
                    case R.id.action_school:
                        nearByPlace("school");
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
        return rootview;
    }

    private void nearByPlace(final String placeType) {
        map.clear();
        String url = getUrl(latitude,longitude,placeType);
        mService.getNearByPlaces(url)
                .enqueue(new Callback<Places>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<Places> call, Response<Places> response) {
                        if(response.isSuccessful()){
                            for(int i = 0; i < response.body().getResults().length;i++){
                                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                                Results googlePlace = response.body().getResults()[i];
                                double lat = Double.parseDouble(googlePlace.getGeometry().getLocation().getLat());
                                double lng = Double.parseDouble(googlePlace.getGeometry().getLocation().getLng());
                                String placeName = googlePlace.getName();
                                String vicitiny = googlePlace.getVicinity();
                                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat,lng);
                                markerOptions.position(latLng);
                                markerOptions.title(placeName);
                                if(placeType.equals("hospital"))
                                    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
                                else if(placeType.equals("market"))
                                    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp));
                                else if(placeType.equals("restaurant"))
                                    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_local_hospital_black_24dp));
                                else if(placeType.equals("school"))
                                    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_school_black_24dp));
                                else
                                    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
                                map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                                map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<Places> call, Throwable t) {

                    }
                });
    }



    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode){
            case MY_PERMISSION_CODE:
            {
                if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                        if(client == null){
                            bulidGoogleApiClient();
                        }
                        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    }
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Permisos denegados",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            break;
        }

    }



    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        map = googleMap;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                bulidGoogleApiClient();
                map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            } else {
                bulidGoogleApiClient();
                map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        lastlocation = location;

        if (currentLocationmMarker != null) {
            currentLocationmMarker.remove();

        }
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latLng)
            .title("Tu posicion")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
        currentLocationmMarker = map.addMarker(markerOptions);
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomBy(11));

        if (client != null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(client, this);
        }
    }

    private String getUrl(double latitude, double longitude, String placeType) {

        StringBuilder googlePlacesUrl = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
        googlePlacesUrl.append("location="+latitude+","+longitude);
        googlePlacesUrl.append("&radius="+10000);
        googlePlacesUrl.append("&type="+placeType);
        googlePlacesUrl.append("&sensor=true");
        googlePlacesUrl.append("&key="+getResources().getString(R.string.browser_key));
        Log.d("getUrl",googlePlacesUrl.toString());
        return googlePlacesUrl.toString();
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

        locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        locationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);


        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(client, locationRequest, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        client.connect();

    }


    public boolean checkLocationPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION))
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{
                        android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                }, MY_PERMISSION_CODE);
            else
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{
                        android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                }, MY_PERMISSION_CODE);
            return false;
        } else
            return true;

    }

    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    }

    public void setContentView(int contentView) {
        this.contentView = contentView;
    }
}
```

I add the fragments at MenuActivity: 
Codes:

```
public class MenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

        final Fragment principalFragment = new PrincipalFragment();
        final Fragment recipeFragment = new RecipeFragment();
        final Fragment addFragment = new AddFragment();
        final Fragment perfilFragment = new SettingsFragment();
        final Fragment shopFragment = new ShopFragment();
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, principalFragment).commit();
        }

        bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);

        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

                if (item.getItemId() == R.id.principalitem) {

                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, principalFragment).commit();
                } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.recetasitem) {
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, recipeFragment).commit();
                } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.additem) {
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, addFragment).commit();
                } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.perfilitem) {
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, perfilFragment).commit();
                } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.shopitem) {
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, shopFragment).commit();
                }
                return true;
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Code xml:

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/activity_menu"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="nutriapp.nut.nut.MenuActivity">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="511dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomNavigationView"

        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:itemIconTint="#000000"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: where are you adding your fragments?

Comment: I added my fragments at activity MenuActivy which I added now at description of the problem. @A.A

Comment: Hide your action bar. The empty space related to the actionbar. You have to consider your action bar theme.

Comment: Thaaankss :) @ErenUtku

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're seeing the white space because you're setting a fixed height on your `frameContainer` that is set above your `bottomNavigationView`..this will leave some space on top of the `frameContainer`

Use this for your activity's layout..

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:itemIconTint="#000000"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

*Update*

You'll have also to remove the action bar in your style

```
<style name="NoActionBar" parent="@android:style/the_style_you_have_chosen">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

and then set it as your activity's theme:

```
<activity android:theme="@style/NoActionBar" ... />
```